# MySQL queries are only giving me the first 20 results in my CakePHP application

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.7

For some reason, I am only getting the first 20 results from my tables being displayed in the application. It doesn't matter how I am calling the database, I still only get the first 20 even though there are more than that in the DB. Is there a configuration in CakePHP I am missing? Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried the examples that are in the CakePHP documentation. There are multiple ways to write it out and I have tried about all of them

**This is using CakePHP's Paginator**

```
$this->loadComponent('Paginator');
$Tform3281d = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Tform3281d->find());
```

**Here is an example without Paginator. Either way, I am only getting the first 20 records**

```
$TdispatchTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Tdispatchinfo')->find()->all();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with CakePHP but are there still only 20 results if you print your results variable? `echo "<pre>"; print_r($TdispatchTable); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: Could you put this variable `public $paginate = ['limit' => 25];` in your controller class and check if the number of records will be 25? Just for we know if is a paginator problem or database problem (or another).